# Passing JSONArray to JQuery outputs Object

Tags: jquery, highcharts, arrays

I want to pass a series to HighCharts using JSON format. I am successfully generating the format at my backend. And also I am getting the response as below:

```
[
    {
        "type":"pie",
        "name":"HighCharts Pie Chart",
        "data": [["xyz",30],["abc",32]]
    }
]
```

I want to use this JSONArray as it is in the HighChart. If I am trying to print it, it's getting `[Object object]`. I have tried assigning to `div` also. Its also not working.

Can you please tell me how to use it directly in HighCharts jQuery?

Thanks

Comment: Your json is correct as you can see http://jsfiddle.net/j4TaW/1/

Comment: If you solved your own problem, you should mark your answer as the accepted answer.

Comment: sorry i didnt see option here. can you tell me where is this option?

Answer (score 1):

I resolved the issue myself :)

Actually document.write takes string as argument so when I was trying to print the response its typecasting to string thatswhy its printing [Object object].

Solution is simple just I have assigned the response to the series in the highchart.

```
option.series = response;
```

its working absolutely fine :)

Comment: Can you give me the js file and the action where you generate the json.I try to make a highchart in asp.net mvc3 and dont know how to pass my data  from my jsonresult method  to javascript

Comment: actually im generating in the backend not in js.